# data cleansing - 2 columns change the data in one column if criteria is met

Tags: python, tuples, where-clause

I have columns with vehicle data, for vehicles greater than 1 year old with mileage less than 100 I want to replace mileage less than 100 with 1000.

my attempts -

```
mileage_corr = vehicle_data_all.loc[(vehicle_data_all["mileage"] < 100) & (vehicle_data_all["year"] < 2020)], 1000

Error - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute
```

and

```
mileage_corr = vehicle_data_all.loc[(vehicle_data_all["mileage"] < 100) & (vehicle_data_all["year"] < 2020)]
mileage_corr['mileage'].where(mileage_corr['mileage'] <= 100, 1000, inplace=True)

error -
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  return self._where(
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing a snippet of what `vehicle_data_all` looks like? Maybe share the result of `vehicle_data_all.head()`

Comment: Manu model year price transmission mileage fuelType tax mpg  eng Size
Audi  A1     2017 12500 Manual       15735 Petrol 150 55.4  1.4
Audi  A6     2016 16500 Automatic 36203 Diesel 20 64.2  2
Audi  A1       2016 11000 Manual         29946 Petrol 30 55.4 1.4
Audi  A4     2017 16800 Automatic 25952 Diesel 145 67.3 2 
Audi  A3     2019 17300 Manual         40         Petrol 145 49.6 1

Comment: thanks for providing but that is extremely difficult to read. Next time, try `df.to_clipboard()`. That will copy to your clipboard and then you can edit your answer to include the data as context.

Answer (score 0):

Without complete information, assuming your `vehicle_data_all` DataFrame looks something like this,

```
    years   mileage
0   2019    192
1   2014    78
2   2010    38
3   2018    119
4   2019    4
5   2012    122
6   2005    50
7   2015    69
8   2004    56
9   2003    194
```

Pandas has a way of assigning based on a filter result. This is referred to as [setting values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

```py
df.loc[condition, "field_to_change"] = desired_change
```

Applied to your dataframe would look something like this,

```py
vehicle_data_all.loc[((vehicle_data_all["mileage"] < 100) & (vehicle_data_all["year"] < 2020)), "mileage"] = 1000
```

This was my result,

```
    years   mileage
0   2019    192
1   2014    1000
2   2010    1000
3   2018    119
4   2019    1000
5   2012    122
6   2005    1000
7   2015    1000
8   2004    1000
9   2003    194
```